# Can we use lightweight charts as component in nextjs and pass data as props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, lightweight-charts

importing in this way

```
const createChart  = dynamic(() => import("lightweight-charts"), { ssr: false });
```

using it in component and passing props

```
<createChart
  options={{
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    timeScale: {
      timeVisible: true,
      secondsVisible: true,
    },
  }}
  candlestickSeries={[{ data: candlestickDataPoints }]}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `createChart` as is directly as a component.
However you can create your own component that could then directly intereact with `createChart`.

Here's a little snippet.

```
import { createChart, CrosshairMode } from 'lightweight-charts';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const CandleStickChart = ({ OHLC_Data }) => {
    const chartContainerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const chart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            timeScale: {
                timeVisible: true,
                secondsVisible: false,
                fixLeftEdge: true,
                fixRightEdge: true,
            },
            crosshair: {
                mode: CrosshairMode.Normal,
            },
        });
        const candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({});

        candleSeries.setData(OHLC_Data);

        return () => {
            chart.remove();
        };
    }, [OHLC_Data]);

    return <div ref={chartContainerRef} />;
};
```